# Notifying Dutch Immigration/Naturalization when moving abroad

Tags: resident-permit, eu, netherlands

I live in the Netherlands and I am currently holding Permanent Residence (PR) status. Soon I will be moving to Sweden and staying temporarily with my sister while searching for a new job.
I would like to deregister myself from where I am currently living. From what I understand after a conversation with Immigration and Naturalisation Service (IND) staff, my PR will still be valid for another 6 years if my next destination is within the EU, meaning if I come back to the Netherlands for long-term stay before 6 years from now, there will be no problem with my PR.

My question is how should I prove my move to IND that once I have moved to Sweden (within the EU, not outside) before I can find a job for a permanent stay in Sweden? And will IND check on that with Sweden government after 90 days of temporary stay?